# Does anybody knows how to add Ivy dependencies into a java web project with IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, ivy, intellij-14

I've got an old project with Ivy and want to import dependencies from enterprise repository with it. Does anybody knows if this is possible with IntelliJ IDEA.
I want to be able to deploy locally with Tomcat after importing dependencies.

Comment: Did you consider https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3612-ivyidea plug-in? Any issues with that?

Comment: I've already tried but would like a native way to do it. Due it's from a thirt-party (non a JetBrains pluging).

Comment: JetBrains has no plans to add Ivy support. Either use a third-party plug-in or switch to Gradle/Maven.

Comment: The thing is I've got three Ivy setup files, so I don't know the difference between those threes. ivy.xml, ivy-soap.xml and ivysettings.xml, where can I look for true documentation for it?

Comment: For instance with IvyIDEA I can only setup ivy.xml and ivysettings.xml but not sure how to add ivy-soap.xml in order to use it too.